# groovy grape verbose

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

Is there a way to print Ivy output when using Groovy Grape.

when I use Grape, it's just hanging there till finishes downloading all dependencies. I would like to know what it's happening and what it's downloading.

Thanks,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like this might be in Groovy 1.7.6

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4014

i.e. `-Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true` in JAVA_OPTS or on the command line

Comment: The download report is useful. It would be better to get true verbose output that includes the repos it's searching

Comment: this is nice but only if it reported why it freezes after this line.. `Preparing to download artifact javax.servlet#servlet-api;2.4!servlet-api.jar`

Answer (score 25):

tim_yates answer is good but if you need to debug a problem with Grapes, then this might be useful:

```
-Divy.message.logger.level=4
```

source: http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/groovy-grape-troubleshooting-failed-download/

Answer (score 12):

For full debugging, you need to use both of these settings exported via `JAVA_OPTS` when running in a Groovy script.

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-Divy.message.logger.level=4 -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true'
./myScript.groovy
```

Answer (score 0):

windows

`set JAVA_OPTS="-Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true -Divy.message.logger.level=4 %JAVA_OPTS%"`

unix

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true -Divy.message.logger.level=4 $JAVA_OPTS"`