# Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2!commons-logging.jar]

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I am started to learn groovy. I like to use httpbuilder. I found out that I should use @Grab so I wrote this example

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
@Grapes(
        @Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpclient', version='4.5.7')
)


import org.apache.http.client.methods.*
import org.apache.http.entity.*
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*
import groovy.json.*
// build JSON

def map = [:]
map["name"] = "Maritime DevCon"
map["address"] = "Fredericton"
map["handle"] = "maritimedevcon"

def jsonBody = new JsonBuilder(map).toString()

// build HTTP POST

def url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
def post = new HttpPost(url)

post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonBody))

// execute

def client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def response = client.execute(post)

def bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))
def jsonResponse = bufferedReader.getText()
println "response: \n" + jsonResponse

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def resultMap = slurper.parseText(jsonResponse)

assert "Maritime DevCon" == resultMap["name"]
assert resultMap["id"] != null
```

I have a working internet connection but I got:

```
Information:Groovyc: While compiling groovyWItholdJava: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2!commons-logging.jar]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
...
```

What can be the cause of this? I can even open mvn central repo in my browser.

Comment: Turn on the grab (ivy) logging and you'll see the error.

Comment: That didn't seem as easy as I thought.

Comment: Your code works for me. Check network settings

Comment: In case you didn't find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722280/groovy-grape-verbose

Comment: Yes @daggett I added those two arguments to groovy. But the output didn't change.

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871792/groovy-grab-download-failed.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details how do you run your code and how did you set logging properties.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @M.Justin this post is too old but check proxy settings I suggest.