# Dependency conflict in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, dependencies, groovy-grape

Hello I created a groovy script and downloaded some dependencies using Grab.
At compile time I have the following exception thrown

```
Caught: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/NodeList used in the signature
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/NodeList used in the signature
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.XMLHelper.parseToDom(XMLHelper.java:223)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomReader.<init>(PomReader.java:122)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:118)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager$MyModuleDescriptorProvider.provideModule(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:817)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.getStale(ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.java:68)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.getStaledMd(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:834)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.cacheModuleDescriptor(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:1326)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.parse(BasicResolver.java:538)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:273)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.getDependency(IBiblioResolver.java:506)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:170)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:718)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:803)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:726)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:791)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:726)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:791)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:726)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:803)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:726)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:599)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:236)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:523)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy$resolve$0.call(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help to find which dependency is causing the problem ?

Comment: grab/grape verbose logging should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722280/groovy-grape-verbose

Comment: And it looks like you are grab-ing something that conflicts with the DOM stuff.

Comment: @daggett I have the log now and I see that after downloading the spark-core pom it fails reading it with the exception above.

Comment: I removed the grab annotations from the script file after downloading the dependencies and it is working now.  Is it how it is supposed to work ??  Seems strange to me

Comment: no. you have 2 dependencies with conflicted version. for example spark-core downloads dom v1 and other dependency downloads dom v2. you could set `transitive=false` flag for grab definitions, but then you have to specify all nested dependencies (from pom) by using grab. That's the only way.

Comment: This needs the actual `@Grab` commands used to be able to properly diagnose.  Voting to close unless that gets added.